# Selecting element in tuple by starting character

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a tuple, doors:

```
    doors = [(2, 'C'), (3, 'G1')]
```

Due to previous shuffling, zipping, and popping of what I originally had: `[(1,'C'),(2,'G1'),(3,'G2')]` doors could also be something like: ***`doors = [(1,'G1'),(2,'G2')]`****
or `doors= [(1,'G2'),(3,'C')]`.

Is there a way I can 'pythonize' by indexing into a tuple to only select elements with the letter 'G' in it (or not to select 'C'), and obtain only the paired integers `1`, `2`, or `3`?

Here's something I have so far that produces an error, and an example of what I would want to obtain, using the example tuple `doors = [(2, 'C'), (3, 'G1')]`:

```
    >>> first_letter = 'G'
    >>> print('Search by:',first_letter)
    Search by: G
    # I want to obtain 'G1' = need_to_select, this is for me to get 3 later
    >>> need_to_select = [door for door in doors if (door[0] in first_letter)]
    need_to_select = G1
```

Then obtain the matching number, so `3`in this case.

But I get this error (line 23 is creating need_to_select):

```
    Traceback (most recent call last): File "python", line 23, in <module>
```

Comment: If you want to get feedback, why your code doesn't work, then you have to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including full error message(s). SO users are not psychics.

Comment: You should always post the complete Traceback.

Answer (score 3):

List comprehension:

```
[i for i, j in doors if 'G' in j]
```

This iterates over the tuples of the `doors` list and gets the first element (the integer) when the second element contains `G`.

Similarly, if you want to get first element when the second does not contain `C`:

```
[i for i, j in doors if not 'C' in j]
```

**Example:**

```
In [56]: doors = [(2, 'C'), (3, 'G1')]

In [57]: [i for i, j in doors if 'G' in j]
Out[57]: [3]

In [60]: [i for i, j in doors if not 'C' in j]
Out[60]: [3]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a functional alternative to [@heemayl's list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48724321/9209546) solution. I would only use this for multiple or more complex criteria, since otherwise list comprehensions are more readable and efficient.

A couple of examples below, where results are given as tuples.

```
doors = [(2, 'C'), (3, 'G1')]

def selector(x):
    return 'G' in x[1]

def selector_not(x):
    return not 'C' in x[1]

list(zip(*filter(selector, doors)))[0]      # (3,)

list(zip(*filter(selector_not, doors)))[0]  # (3,)
```